# Why won't androidx support the navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

So I'm trying to get a navigation drawer done using this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc&t=16s) however, I undersetand that something has changed in Android Studio since the tutorial was uploaded with AndroidX and toolbars and stuff, but I'm not sure what has changed.

I've been trying for hours to understand the problem but I'm new to android studio so I'm clueless. The app just keeps crashing

Basically, I just don't know what to import in regards to the toolbar to make it work

This is the main activity info thats relevant

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the logcat error

```
2019-11-09 13:53:58.560 5972-5972/? I/ample.fyptrial: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-11-09 13:53:58.614 5972-5972/? W/ample.fyptrial: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-11-09 13:53:59.891 5972-5972/com.example.fyptrial1 W/ample.fyptrial: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-09 13:53:59.893 5972-5972/com.example.fyptrial1 W/ample.fyptrial: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-11-09 13:53:59.899 5972-5972/com.example.fyptrial1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-09 13:53:59.922 5972-5972/com.example.fyptrial1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fyptrial1, PID: 5972
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fyptrial1/com.example.fyptrial1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.fyptrial1-QrFsh8JGp3aVPMyDmmBcJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.fyptrial1-QrFsh8JGp3aVPMyDmmBcJA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.fyptrial1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-11-09 13:53:59.983 5972-5972/com.example.fyptrial1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5972 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your build.gradle module and your crash logs

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. Change it to `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

remove androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar from parent view and use below xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: please try this one

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are using the drawer layout from support compat you have to use the material drawer layout

Here is how to add the library

https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Here is how to add the drawer

https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace.

Looks like you are using some of the support library classes in your xmls as you can see in the logs:

```
Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList
    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

In your xml that is being inflated in the MainActivity, replace this:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

with this:

```
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

This should solve this error for you.

However, I am positive there will be more xmls with older support library classes. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) and search for the class causing the error as above and replace it with the corresponding androidx class.